# Changing icon programmatically of a UIBarButton item in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a UIBarButton item `getItem` that I want change the icon of programmatically. I have it set to the search icon through the Xcode interface builder. I want to **change** it to the camera icon programmatically.

Is there any way to do this in Xamarin?

Comment: when you say "identifier" do you mean "icon"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a method which are called each time I would like to update my toolbar (also the icons).

```
private void UpdateToolbar()
{
    // Check which items should be visible and add it to the list
    var itemlist = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();

    var img = IsCorrect ? "Icon_Correct" : "Icon_incorrect";
    var mybtn= CreateToolbarItem(img);

    itemlist.Add(mybtn);

    // Set toolbaritems
    SetToolbarItems(itemlist.ToArray(), false);
}

public static UIBarButtonItem CreateToolbarItem(String name)
{
    var btn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
    btn.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle(name), UIControlState.Normal);
    btn.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 32, 32);

    return new UIBarButtonItem(btn);
}
```

Just reset the toolbar with the array of your buttons.

This works for me. Above code is just an example. In my implementation the array has a length between 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just use SetImage method on the button.